# Erro com APNS Server usando PHP

Tags: php, ssl, xampp, apple-push-notification, apns

Criei um pequeno APNS Server usando PHP, usando uma versão antiga do Xampp. Porém quando fui usar o arquivo de push em uma versão atual, recebi o erro conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A linha do erro a qual é referenciada acima, é esta:

```
// Servidor de produção0
$fp = stream_socket_client( 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

Acredito que a função stream_socket_client esteja antiquada, como não sou especialista na área de PHP, gostaria de saber se é este o problema, e se for, como poderia substituir ou atualizar essa função.

Comment: O erro diz que a verificação do certificado falhou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realizei alguns testes:

- Usando o Xampp 5.6 -> Apresentou o erro relatado na questão
- Usando o Console do Mac (PHP Nativo com versão 5.5) -> Funcionou normalmente
- Usando o Xampp 5.5 -> Também funcionou normalmente.

  Acredito que alguma configuração ou atualização no Xampp 5.6 esteja afetando o acesso ao arquivo *.pem em disco, impossibilitando a criação de conexão com a APNS.

  Caso alguém conheça esse problema na versão 5.6 e conheça a solução agradeço se comentar ou complementar essa solução que encontrei.

Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Fala ae @tiago então cara, criei um código bem similar ao seu, mas a apple me retorna $err = 0, "Falha para conectar: 0", você saberia o que poderia ser isto? (eu hospedei meu php em um site de host gratuito "ptblogs.com")

Comment: Pow, pelo que sei, as portas que a APNS usa para receber os push são bloqueadas em hosts de sites(2195 e 2196). Voce precisaria ou colocar isso em uma maquina em sua casa, ou usar um serviço grande como AWS ou Azure para ter uma maquina virtual. Mas no caso, a AWS e a Azure possuem esse serviço pronto.

Comment: o problema estava com a minha porta, onde não se conectava com a porta da APNS, assim que subi para um servidor, funcionou perfeitamente, agradeço o feedback